# Python: how to add 1 to every integer in a file

Tags: python, file, replace

I have a script that contains indexes pertaining to the matching key in the dictionary.  A recent change requires me to shift all of the numbers over 1 (add 1 to each number).  For example, if the file was to contain the following:

```
form['formA'] = {
  'title': 'titleA',
  'number': 3,
  'numbers': [1,2,4,5]
}

form['formB'] = {
  'title': 'titleB',
  'number': 7,
  'numbers': [8,9,10,11]
}
```

I would like every integer to be one larger.  So it would become:

```
form['formA'] = {
  'title': 'titleA',
  'number': 4,
  'numbers': [2,3,5,6]
}

form['formB'] = {
  'title': 'titleB',
  'number': 8,
  'numbers': [9,10,11,12]
}
```

Between all of the type errors, attribute errors, and just destroying the formatting, I can't figure out how to do this.  Here's what's probably my closest attempt:

```
#read from the file
f = open(currdir, 'r')
content = f.readlines()
f.close()

addbrackets = False    #is it a list
for line in content:
    if "form" not in line:
        #grab only the values to the right of the colon
        rightside = line.split(":")[-1]
        list_of_nums = rightside

        #remove brackets
        if "[" in rightside:
            addbrackets = True
            removebrackets = rightside.replace("[","").replace("]","")
            list_of_nums = removebrackets.split(",")

        #search for all integers in the list and add 1
        for num in list_of_nums:
            if type(num) is int:
                num += 1
                numindex = list_of_nums.index(num)
                list_of_nums[numindex] = num

        #plug new values into content
        lineindex = content.index(line)
        if addbrackets:
            content[lineindex] = line.replace(rightside, "[" + ",".join(list_of_nums))[:-1] + "],"
            addbrackets = False
        else:
            content[lineindex] = line.replace(rightside, "".join(list_of_nums))

#write to the new file
f = open(newdir, 'w')
f.write("".join(content))
f.close()
```

However, this just manages to mess up the formatting.  Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You put equal signs `=` in you example files and use colon `:` in your script. I suppose one is wrong but which ? And can you be sure that integers are always inside brackets, and that a list is always on one single line ?

Comment: they should be colons, sorry about that.  Each key is unique to being either a list or a number.  Also, the lists are not necessarily on the same line - good point.

Comment: This data looks JSONish. Outside of the quick and dirty regexes answered below: the "proper" solution is more than likely to run or write a parser to structure the data, then write it back out once it's changed.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to do that though :/ the most I did with parsing was a compiler class and that was a disaster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to keep the formatting and want to be indiscriminant about what you reformat (e.g. all integers separated by word boundaries), then this is a simple regular expression search/replace, you'll want to search for a word boundary (`\b`), any number of consecutive integers (`\d+`) and then a terminating word boundary (`\b`).  This will increment numbers in strings like `'foo 15 bar'`, `'[1]'`, `'[1, 2]'`, but not `'foo15bar'` or `'foo15'`:

```
import re
with open(yourfilename) as fin:
  s = fin.read()
print re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', lambda m: str(int(m.group())+1), s)
```

If I assign your data to `s` as a string an run the final line, I get:

```
form['formA'] = {
  'title' = 'titleA',
  'number' = 4,
  'numbers' = [2,3,5,6]
}

form['formB'] = {
  'title' = 'titleB',
  'number' = 8,
  'numbers' = [9,10,11,12]
}
```

which seems to be what you want.  Of course, if you have some numbers that you want don't want to increment, then this won't work -- You'll need a smarter way to parse the file.

Comment: well that worked.  Can you explain to me what exactly is going on, though? hehe I've worked with regular expressions by hand, but have never actually implemented them in the code; still, the lambda is prob what's getting me.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions:

```
foo="""
form['formA'] = {
  'title' = 'titleA',
  'number' = 3,
  'numbers' = [1,2,4,5]
}

form['formB'] = {
  'title' = 'titleB',
  'number' = 7,
  'numbers' = [8,9,10,11]
}
"""

def incNumbers(s):
  def inc(m):
    return str(int(m.group())+1)
  return re.sub(r'(\d+)', inc, s)


def go(m):
  return m.group(1) + incNumbers(m.group(2))

r = re.compile('^( *\'numbers?\' =)(.*)', re.MULTILINE)
print re.sub(r, go, foo)
```

Comment: A great alternative to mgilson's approach if you needed to be a little more sensitive to which numbers get incremented.

Comment: hmmm.  So is this the kind of thing that would work if I want to increment only values greater than, let's say, 5?